# Wordpress + .ajaxForm can't read POST or SESSION

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I've set sessions in Wordpress in a functions.php file.  I'm using [ajaxForm](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) to submit a form on a Wordpress page to itself.  Firebug tells me that I'm submitting my $_POST correctly, but I cannot access it on the page itself.  I'm trying to compare a session value that gets set on that page with a POST value that gets posted back to the page.  I can see output the session value to the page, but despite what Firebug tells me, I cannot output the POST.

Thoughts?

Here's some code:

AJAX

```
  jQuery('#contactform').ajaxForm({
  url: 'http://www.someURLhere.com/wp-content/themes/bahrmanlaw/loop-page.php',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSubmit: function() {
    jQuery('#contactform').validate();
    return jQuery('#contactform').valid();
  },
  success: function() {
    jQuery('#lookpage').hide();
    jQuery('#message').fadeIn(1500, function() {});
  }
  });
```

HTML

```
<form name="contact" action="" id="contactform" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="fullname" id="fullname_label">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" title="Please enter a valid name." class="required" />
      <input type="image" class="button" id="button" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/send.png'; ?>" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php echo $_POST['fullname']; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried performing the request without the use of AJAX?

Comment: Good thought, but I did try that.  I can read it with no problem, both to another page or posted to the same page.  Additionally, I can see the $_POST values in Firebug, so I would think they are going through.  Good thought, though.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api. The ajaxForm method does not submit the form, it only prepares it.

Comment: I was under the impression that when using ajaxForm, the form is submitted when the 'submit' button of the form is pressed.  ajaxSubmit submits the form immediately.  It mentions this in the jquery.form.js file itself.

Comment: The example in the documentation suggests otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

I am able to read it using this:

```
<?php 
    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
    var_dump($request_body); 
?>
```

Is necessary to parse it, but the binary data is there